# How to deploy mofs and regs file to SFCB in ESX 4.x correctly,

Tags: esx, authorize.net-cim

I am working on one cimom based solution in ESX. ESX4.x uses sfcb as a default cimom daemon and sfcb gives specifications (sourceforge) on how to develop MOF and reg files for the providers in the sfcb.

WE have already developed the MOF and REG files as per the specifications and ported and deployed them in RHEL, SLES boxes. While porting the same MOFs and Regs in the ESX, I believe there is some different step in ESX than what is defined in sfcb specification.

I require those steps to port and deploy those files in the SFCB, so that our software can work on the ESX.

Revert back if there is any confusion, comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These option are for esx 4.x and upwards only.

**Mof registration are the same.**

**There are multiple things to do to register your reg file for cimom.**

> sfcbstage -r $REGFILENAME
>
> cp $REGFILENAME /var/lib/sfcb/registration

Note:
Please make sure your registration file ends with the name providerRegister rather than the .reg extension (though not completely validated but some as per OS-level, making it similar)

**Build the Repository**

> sfcbrepos -f -c /var/lib/sfcb/schema

**Restart Sfcb**

> /etc/init.d/sfcbd-watchdog restart.